# how to connect facebook through xmpp dll in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, facebook, agsxmpp

I tried the code below to connect to Facebook through Agsxmpp.Dll, but when I connect to it, it shows login failed on OnAuthError Event. How do I solve this?

```
ObjAgx = New XmppClientConnection
ObjAgx.Server = "chat.facebook.com"
ObjAgx.Username = txtusername.text
ObjAgx.Password = txtPassword.Text
ObjAgx.Port = 5222
ObjAgx.AutoResolveConnectServer = False

objAgx.open()
```

Is there any method to connect to Facebook using xmpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the right Code :

```
ObjAgx = New XmppClientConnection
ObjAgx.Server = "chat.facebook.com"
ObjAgx.Username = txtusername.text
ObjAgx.Password = txtPassword.Text
ObjAgx.Port = 5222
ObjAgx.AutoResolveConnectServer = True
ObjAgx.UseSSL = False
ObjAgx.ConnectServer = "Facebookmail.com"
ObjAgx.open()
```

you must turn off ssl to connect to facebook and use the connectserver as you see in the code above .

*NOTE* : AutoResolveConnectServer is needed and it's IMPORTANT .

Happy Coding ^^